# Theoretical Enneaquark?

Tags: elementary-particles, subatomic

First of all I'm new to physics. I'm teaching my self as of late and I'm wondering if a particle composed of 4 up quarks and 5 down(= 1 charge) could theoretically form a 'stable' particle under the right conditions. Am I on the right track or is this COMPLETELY wrong? -JW

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvnvG.jpg

Comment: Unfortunately the site is not for discussion of personal theories.  Maybe you can flesh out the question with some calculations to at least support your hypothesis?

Comment: Posting images of text or hand-written notes is actively discouraged on Physics SE. Please lookup the terms "pentaquark" and "tetraquark".

Answer (score 4):

A tritium nucleus or “triton” has 4 $u$ and 5 $d$ quarks and is reasonably stable with a half-life of 12.32 years. But no one calls it an enneaquark.

Your mass estimate is about two orders of magnitude too low, probably because you are only adding up the quark’s masses and ignoring their kinetic energy and their gluonic binding energy.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd classify a Tritium nucleus as a single particle in the sense the pentaquark and tetraquark (or just plain old 3 and 3 quark particles) are.  Maybe you could expand on why you consider it is a particle (if you do).  Thanks.

Comment: @StephenG I don’t have a strong opinion and I don’t think there is a standard definition of what counts as a non-elementary “particle”. It doesn’t seem far-fetched to me to say that a triton is as much a particle as a neutron (they’re both unstable bound states of quarks), but if others don’t agree I won’t argue with them. A triton does have a longer half-life than a neutron, so that’s one count in its favor. And the terminology “triton” sure sounds particle-y.

Comment: @StephenG I of course acknowledge that in a triton the quarks are more strongly bound first into protons and neutrons than the protons and neutrons are then bound into the triton.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  My own view also relates to the binding mechanism.  That is, in the Tritium nucleus the force between a neutron and proton is the strong nuclear one rather than the "pure" quark-gluon-quark binding "inside" neutrons and protons.